# maven is not downloading any dependency that I have add

Tags: java, maven

I have install maven and JDK and tried to create maven project and add some dependencies, as you can see in the screenshot but the dependency is not downloading so I can not import. can you help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: screenshots added now

Comment: yes I have did clean build and its failed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you are using `dependencyManagement`, where you only specify dependency meta-information, but not the actual dependencies.

More details about managing dependencies via Maven you can find here:

[maven dependency mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

[maven dependency management](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management)

Answer (score 0):

Change the version of guice to 4.1.0

What it seems like there is no 4.1

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.inject/guice